# Network Connection Timed out cuando inicio mi sesión de Putty

Tags: redes, virtualización, networking, putty

Fue capaz connectarme a mi maquina virtual con Putty durante los dos últimos días:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero desde esta manana obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben lo que puede crear este error y ¿Cómo deshacerse de él? Cambiamento de IP?

Esta máquina virtual es una Fedora que de momento va muy bien

Aqui es el ifconfig de la maquina Fedora a la cual quiero connectarme:

```
[ac@localmachine data-tools]$ ifconfig
br-4bcf98dfca2a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.29.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:eff:fe64:a9fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:0e:64:a9:fd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:0f:72:db:f7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.153.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.153.255
        inet6 fe80::75d0:2219:7b3b:97c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:c8:b8:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 671764  bytes 836534330 (797.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 139028  bytes 17062558 (16.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 196184  bytes 31675520 (30.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196184  bytes 31675520 (30.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth0d56971: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::605d:1eff:fe75:6bea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 62:5d:1e:75:6b:ea  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 86913  bytes 10046500 (9.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87236  bytes 20449239 (19.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:71:e2:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Es porque necesita redirigir el puerto TCP externo 4662 al puerto 22 en su máquina local? Como hacer eso?

Aqui estan los archivos en el directory de la máquina a la que quiero conectarme:

```
[ac@localmachine data-tools]$ cat /etc/ssh/
moduli                    sshd_config.d/            ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ssh_config                ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_config.d/             ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
sshd_config               ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

Aqui esta la pagina de Firewall de la maquina desde cual quiero connectarme a Fedora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aunque los elimine todos sigo teniendo el mismo problema.

Ahora quiero saber si el servidor SSH está ejecutándose en el fedora. Entonces intenté:

```
root@localmachine ac]# sudo service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status httpd.service
○ httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor pr>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
```

Pero no parece estar relacionado al servidor SSH. Entonces intenté  compruebar si el proceso sshd se está ejecutando:

```
[root@localmachine ac]# ps aux | grep sshd
root        5787  0.0  0.1  30536  6656 ?        Ss   Jul08   0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root       48866  0.0  0.0 221528   788 pts/0    S+   13:18   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

Y saber si esta escuchando el port 22:

```
[root@localmachine ac]# netstat -plant | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5787/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      5787/sshd: /usr/sbi
```

Entonces intenté desahcerme con el Firewall en el lado de la VM:

```
systemctl disable firewalld;
```

Pero persiste el error.

Comment: Mira el puerto donde está escuchando el servidor SSH de la máquina a la que te quieres conectar. Lo tienes en el archivo de configuración del ssh

Comment: Muchas gracias para su comentario @Juan . He actualizado mi pregunta con todos los archivos del directorio /etc/ssh de la máquina a la que quiero connectarme. ¿puede decirme dónde debo buscar?

Comment: En principio en sshd_config debes tener una linea Port xxxx el número xxxx es el puerto que está usando el servidor . Mira ver si es 22 o 4662.

Comment: Si, es 22 @Juan

Comment: Entonces la conexión no es aceptada por algún firewall. Mira el firewall de windows y el firewall del fedora. Ah, ¿porqué citas el puerto 4662?

Comment: Aggg, acabo de fijarme en la imagen que envías y veo que en el campo IP pones ac@. Hasta donde yo se ahí debe ir la IP de la máquina remota (sin ac@)

Comment: **puerto 4662**: Sí, lo siento, me equivoqué @Juan ... Pensé que no estaba usando el puerto 22 en la máquina remota! **ac**: Sí, pero la captura de pantalla es de la máquina a la que me tengo que conectar. **firewall** acabo de compartir el screenshot de mi firewall windows, estoy buscando para Fedora

Comment: Si @Juan, Creo que hay un problema con la ruta a su VM o el servidor SSH no está funcionando

Comment: Recopitulano: Te quieres conectar a la máquina 192.168.153.128 en el puerto 22 y tienes el error time out.
La configuración sshd tiene el puero de escucha en 22. Bien.
¿Has comprobado que el servidor está ejecutándose en el fedora?
Lo normal es que fedora tenga el puerto 22 abierto, pero comprueba
Puedes desactivar la firewall de windows pea ver si es ésta la que bloquea.

Comment: Sí, acabo de comprobar que el servidor está ejecutando ssh en el lado de la máquina virtual @Juan (acabo de compartir el resultado en la pregunta). He desactivado las 3 opciones del firewall pero me da lo mismo error. Es possible que es el Firewall de la VM que me crea estos problema. Voy a probar desactivarlos

Comment: Está duro esto. ¿Desde la propia máquina virtual puedes acceder al servidor ssh?

Comment: ¿La MV está en el mismo equipo físico? ¿Cuál virtualizador usas y cómo está configurada la red ahí?

Comment: No soy un profesional de SSH, @Juan pero es mi VM de Fedora (que está en mi ordenador Windows normal) la que genera el servidor SSH y accedo a él por el protocolo SSH desde mi ordenador Windows normal

Comment: La MV esta en el mismo equipo fisico @Sal Utilisor VMWare Workstation 16 para esta MV, Fedora

Comment: Como yo lo veo si desde la MV accedes al servidor sshd es un problema de red (aunque sea una red virtual) si no accedes es un problema de servidor.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).